# file handler in perl not working in subroutine

Tags: perl

```
#!/bin/perl

open( $WP, ">/home/Octa.txt" );

# Subroutine test
sub test {   
    $var1 = shift; 
    print $WP "TESTING\n"; 
}

# Subroutine func
sub func {
    $var = shift;    

    if ( $var eq "Ocat" ) { 
        print $WP "String found\n"; 
        test($var); 
    }
    else { 
        print $WP "String not found\n"; 
    } 
}

$var3 = "Octa"; 
func($var3);
```

The issue is that the code is not able to write anything within the `test` subroutine or within the `if` condition of the 'func`subroutine, but it prints in the`else` part of the 'func' subroutine.

Comment: Seems like a simple typo: Try replace `"Ocat"` in the `if` condition with `"Octa"` :)

Comment: Please use `strict`, `warnings` and Don't Open Files in the old way, Use 3-argument `open` like `open my $in, '>', $filename; or die $!;`

Comment: Man, `test` is called conditionally, so don't expect it to always be there

Comment: It's called a *file handle* (because it holds onto a resources), not a *file handler* (because it doesn't handle anything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, there is a typo -- you test `$var` against `"Ocat"`, while `Octa` is intended.

So the `test` subroutine never gets called and only `String not found` is printed.

With that corrected and *with the output file in a user writeable location*, your program works.

However, some improvements are necessary.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'Octa.txt';
open my $WP, '>', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my $var3 = "Octa"; 
func($WP, $var3);

#Subroutine test
sub test{   
    my ($fh, $var1) = @_; 
    print $fh "TESTING\n"; 
}

#Subroutine func
sub func{
    my ($fh, $var) = @_; 
    if ($var eq "Octa"){ 
        print $fh "String found\n"; 
        test($fh, $var); 
    }   
    else { 
        print $fh "String not found\n"; 
    }   
}
```

I've changed the output file name since a user normally may not write to `/home` directory.

Comments

- It is much better to use the three-argument form of `open`, in which case you get a lexical file handle which can be passed around nicely and is scoped. This question is a good example of how a global file handle can make things confusing, to say the least.
- *Always* check the `open` call. For one thing, can you really write to `/home` directory?
- Please *always* start programs with `use warnings;` and `use strict;`

There is another possibility for failure, which brings together practices in the comments above.

A file in `/home` normally isn't writeable by a user, in which case the posted program cannot work.

But without a check of `open` (which will fail) and without `use warnings` (which would be printed every time we touch the invalid `$WH` filehandle) we *will not see* any of these errors; instead, the program will quietly run and complete but it won't write the output file.

Comment: Thanks . But the print in 'test' and in the 'if' condition of 'func' subroutine are not printed

Comment: @tester  Can you try with the posted program, verbatim?  Normally you shouldn't be able to write to `/home` as a user, and if you only fixed a typo the code in the question won't let you know anything (since `open` is not checked for success).  So it simply won't open the file. The program I posted works for me.

Comment: @tester I edited the answer a little, and added a paragraph at the end, that (hopefully) better explains the comment above.